# Counting occurrences of specific words in excel file, using python and xlrd

Tags: python, xlrd, import-from-excel

I have these excel sheets and I've created a python script which uses xlrd to read these scripts and summarise the information into a .txt file which it generates. As part of the summary, I need it to count the number of times that specific keywords such as "cloud" appears in these excel files. The problem is when I read the cells and split up the string into individual words, it adds quotation marks and \n amongst these words so the counter misses them. Here is my code.

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
count+=1

if filename.find('xls') != -1:
    print filename        
    workbook=xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
    sheet=workbook.sheet_by_name("Details")
    values = []
    newvalues = []
    for row in range(sheet.nrows):
        for col in range(sheet.ncols):
            values.append(sheet.cell(row,col).value)
    newvalues = str(values).split();
    a=[item.replace("\n", "") for item in newvalues]
print a.count("cloud")
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some data (perhaps a link to the excel file?) This would help in understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: Can you post an example of the "cloud" string received from the file?

Comment: A lot of the text when split comes out like this "u'They" or like this "u'Positive'," or \\n\\nInstalled . The quotation marks haven't been added by me